How to use OPENJSON in EF Core
I have a model which contains string Parameters, but in code I do serialize Dictionary<string,object> with a JsonSerializer and store it to that field.
In pure SQL, I can query dictionary fields with functions like OPENJSON and JSON_VALUE and so on.
Is there any way I can do the same while accessing the DbContext and query this field for specific key/value pair?

EF is an ORM, not a database driver. Its job is to Map Objects to Relational data, not execute SQL. You can map actual entities to JSON columns since EF Core 7 without using OPENJSON. You could write SQL directly or map OPENSJON itself to a function, but what's the point? You'll be doing the same thing as using ADO.NET directly, with a lot more code and overhead
